# Sortable animation not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am new with JavaScript and jQuery. My problem is moving between two lists. The animation is not showing. Here is exactly what I mean:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5zv1r69/)

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.sortableclass').sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortableclass",
        opacity: 0.7,
        cursor:'move',
        cancel: ".collection-header",
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to connect the lists, follow this link https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists and provide css

Comment: What kind of animation are you talking about?